# adding several lines of text to an Access database

Tags: ms-access-2007, oledbconnection

Would like to know what the best option is for adding several lines of text to a field of an access database(more than 255 characters of text). The text would be a recipe for example or the method of making the dish. Is it possible to add a textfile to a field of an access database for example?

Kind regards

Comment: How do you wish to modify the database. Is it from a script or Form inside the database or are you modifying it externally. Like uploading a file in a web-site and then adding it to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Memo field type. It stores up to 63,999 characters.

Here are the details:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/field-data-types-available-in-access-mdb-HP005238518.aspx

OLE Object also let you store Word Documents and so on. So you can try using it if you are still short with 63,999 characters.

Hope this helps you